# What is this bottom bracket tool called?

Tags: bottom-bracket, tools, terminology

[image]

[image]

[image]

I came across [this](https://www.amazon.in/dp/B078P9HDDR/?coliid=IHDJJJPZ46TYI&colid=SMSOFZ6A4VJI&psc=1&ref_=list_c_wl_lv_ov_lig_dp_it) tool on **Amazon India**, to remove the bottom bracket.

I don't know what this tool is called.

I've seen similar tools at **motor workshops**, so I'm assuming it is a common tool and not just specific to bicycles.

When I asked for the name of this tool, the mechanics called it something in their local lingo.

I want know what this tool is called in **English.**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is a pin spanner. The photographs and product listing were made by someone who doesn't know about bikes.

You never put it on sprocket or gear teeth. Also, to know the tool you're buying is useful for the purpose you need, you need to know the size of the pins, because there's a few sizes out there on various parts. Based on other pictures of the same tool elsewhere on the internet, this is probably on the  chunky side (around 2.9-3mm pins, comparable to Park SPA-3).

[image]

It is true these are used to remove the kind of single speed freewheels that don't have removal tool fittings, such as the one pictured. The outer race is removed with the pin spanner and the inner race is clamped in a vise, and then you throw the whole thing away and put a new one on.

Answer (score 5):

I would call it a Pin Spanner, and I agree with Jeff, there's no way it would remove a freewheel.  These are designed to fit into a pair of holes in a cover plate where there is no space for a hex fitting.  They're not common on bikes, but the end-plate of a freewheel might have such recesses.

Birzman calls it a Pin Wrench and looks similar to your example.
  https://www.birzman.com/products_2.php?uID=2&cID=28&Key=130

[image]

Park has the `SPA-2` at https://www.parktool.com/en-us/product/pin-spanner-red-spa-2  which looks like this:

[image]

Comment: @mellowmonk  In your lowest picture, there are two holes visible in the side of the freewheel.  That's exactly the fitting for a pin spanner to use.  It will do nothing as pictured.   Also, I wouldn't pay more than a few dollars for that junk tool - it would be lucky to survive its first usage.

Comment: I do want to remove an old freewheel that has those 2 round holes (pretty sure there is a term for it). I'll be glad if the tool works a couple of times, once for the removal & once for the installation. The tool's cost is about $4 here. Will get it to take it to tool shops as a reference to find a better quality tool for future restorations.

Comment: One of my friends said that he has a similar tool that he uses it on the angle grinder. But its way too smol for bicycles.

Comment: @MellowMonk yes the angle grinder also uses a pin spanner style.  They normally come with a tool that has pins at the right separation for the grinder and generally work well.   The tool in your pictures has a hinge and will adjust for holes of variable spacing.  Do note the diameter of the pins is fixed and should be a close fit on the holes - more metal is better here to prevent snapping.

Comment: Yes, the angle grinder ones have much fatter pins than anything I've seen on a bike.  But the Park, while it might have the right diameter, tends to spring out if you need to apply a lot of torque.  Next time I'd get one like the Birzman

Comment: I suspect that they're trying to show that with chain roller sized pins installed it can be used as a chain whip? Not that you need one with a SS freewheel like that.

Comment: I think they're trying to show that they have no idea what the tool is for. It wouldn't be the first time an online merchant does that. I have no idea why would you ever need a chain whip with a freewheel.

Comment: By the way, the picture showing it at bottom bracket is somehow correct. This type of bottom bracket has adjustable cup that is tightened in place with large lock ring, similar to top and bottom nuts on threaded headset. Once the lock ring is loose, the adjustable cup doesn't need much torque to turn.

Comment: Wrench and spanner are variants of the same type of tool. There's also a C-wrench/spanner to engage with the edge of the ring shown in your photo.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd yes true - that's a hook spanner and would work for the lockring.  Some hook spanners use a round pin and are to go in a single hole that is radial (sometimes used on hydraulic cylinder nuts), as opposed to OP's tool which expects two holes parallel to the axle.